# Synchronising OIDC Provider and User Table

Tags: java, authentication, oauth2, oauth

I asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644250/store-users-in-my-database-with-external-auth-provider) which is related to this.

In this question, I propose exchanging a token from my OIDC provider for a token in my own custom OIDC provider, which becomes the ultimate token directly referencing the database user.

What's the best way to tackle this problem in general - I can't be the first person who's run into this, right?

Comment: Connections with other providers or other user stores are often available out-the-box (Your SO post specifically mentions Auth0 whose docs describe this:  https://auth0.com/docs/identityproviders)

Comment: @BenCottrell That's not exactly what I'm looking for. The document you shared talks about `Identity-Provider -> Auth0` connection. I'm trying to create a `Auth0 -> Application` connection, such that there's a `Identity-Provider -> Auth0 -> Application` Flow, where the ultimate user is stored in the Application - not Auth0.